# retrieve all data of nsarray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm using JSON parsing to get data from MySql by using php
I got all data I want, But when I want to print this data I created a for loop but It gives me the last element only .. this is my code

in DidViewLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
```

`NSString *phpUrl = @"http://dt-works.com/eman/bookOwn.php"; 
NSString *dbName = @"dbName";
NSString *localHost = @"localhost";
NSString *dbUser = @"dbUser";
NSString *dbPwd = @"dbPwd";

int u_id = 1;
NSString *user_id = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",u_id];

SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phpUrl]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"dbName=%@&localHost=%@&dbUser=%@&dbPwd=%@&user_id=%@&submit=", dbName, localHost, dbUser, dbPwd, user_id];

[request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
int arraySize = [statuses count];


for (NSDictionary *status in statuses)
{

    bo_id2 = [status objectForKey:@"bo_id"];
    bo_name2 = [status objectForKey:@"bo_name"];
    bo_au_id2 = [status objectForKey:@"bo_au_id"];
    bo_pub_id2 = [status objectForKey:@"bo_pub_id"];
    bo_num_pages2 = [status objectForKey:@"bo_num_pages"];
    bo_publish_year2 = [status objectForKey:@"bo_publish_year"];
}

NSLog(@"size of array is: %d", arraySize);

for (int i=0; i<arraySize; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%d:",i);
    // here I want to retrieve all array elements .. when I try 
     NSLog(@"Book id: %@ - book name: %@", bookId, bookName); 
      // this give me the last elemet only not all data 
      // I want to get the data here to use it later .. how ???

}`

}

any help ??

Comment: You are printing a variable inside a loop. It will print same value every time. This is not a question that need that need support.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to just be reassigning the values of each object to an instance variable, an instance variable only points to one object, not all the ones you assign it to.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the data?

Comment: I want to retrieve it, not just the last element because I want to insert it to sqlite3 table

Comment: As you iterate through statuses add each status content to the database

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why you have to use two `for` loop to finish the task, in your first loop

```
NSMutableArray *books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSDictionary *status in statuses){
  [books addObject:status];
}
```

Later when you want to retrieve any books, you can just call `[books objectAtIndex:index]`.
Hopefully this can help. 
You should be able to finish all the tasks you asked for.

**Edit**
If you just want just one element, bo_name for example you can use:

```
NSMutableArray *books =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSDictionary *status in statuses){
    [books addObject:[status objectForKey:@"bo_name"]];
}
```

Comment: because I want to use it again later with other things so I need other for loop , and when I use it , it gives me the last element only of the array and I want all the elements .. :(

Comment: I mean you can print the elements in the first loop, try to add: NSLog(@"Book id: %@", [status objectForKey:@"bo_id"]); in the first loop to see if you can print them all?

Comment: yes it prints them normally, but this is not my full target, I print them to ensure that they are ok or not , I want to retrieve them in another line to use later..

Comment: Try this: 
NSMutableArray *book = nil;
for(NSDictionary *status in statuses){
    bo_id2 = [status objectForKey:@"bo_id"];
    bo_name2 = [status objectForKey:@"bo_name"];
    bo_au_id2 = [status objectForKey:@"bo_au_id"];
    bo_pub_id2 = [status objectForKey:@"bo_pub_id"];
    bo_num_pages2 = [status objectForKey:@"bo_num_pages"];
    bo_publish_year2 = [status objectForKey:@"bo_publish_year"];
    NSDictionary *book = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:....];
    [books addObject:book];
}

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to add code in comment. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: never mind , could youu send it to me in my mail eman87aa@hotmail.com  please ??

Comment: @Jason just edit your original answer instead of putting large amounts of code in comments

Comment: ok your answer helpful , but if I want just all (bo_name) from status, how to get it ???

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you must have been reintializing the array some where. Check that in the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"Book id: %@ - book name: %@", bookId, bookName);
```

How do you get the bookId and bookName values in the NSLog above?  Something missing in your code there.

You can try this :

```
for(NSDictionary *status in statuses) {
   NSLog(@"Book id: %@ - Book Name: %@", [status objectForKey:@"bo_id"], [status objectForKey: @"bo_name"]);
}
```

In other terms, if you want to use a second for loop, go the same way as the first one.